# What is a TEX in OpenCL?

Tags: assembly, opencl, object-code

What is TEX in the object code of my OpenCL program? I put my kernel in the kernel analyzer and I saw the label TEX in the object code. I'm not sure what it means. I didn't find the description in the APP SDK guide. Can you direct me to a resource?

Comment: Can you provide several lines from object code with tex label in it?

Answer (score 1):

in the http://gpgpu.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/E1-OpenCL-Architecture.pdf TEX is used as short name of Texture, for example "Tex L2" = Texture Level 2 Cache.

I assume, tex is for "texture memory" section. Texture memory is special kind of memory access, which is used by GPU.